# Can you prevent Xcode from substituting text in a project template?

Tags: xcode, templates, project, xcode-template

I have a project template called Foo. Xcode is replacing all the files and tokenizing all the `___PROJECTNAME___` and `___PROJECTNAMEASIDENTIFIER___` inside the files. In one of the source files I have

```
FooObject *foo = [FooObject fooWithName:@"foo"];
```

Xcode is replacing Foo in FooObject to the newly named project:

```
MyNewProjectObject *foo = [MyNewProjectObject fooWithName:@"foo"];
```

Is there a way that I can prevent this?

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 0):

After lots of futzing around I believe the answer is to make your template project name unique enough that it doesn't match any of your class names.